# Clear textboxes and comboboxes c #

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to clear all the textboxes, comboboxes and reset numericupdown back to zero on pressing a button.

Whats the best way to do that. Sorry if somebody finds this q stupid.

Comment: Is this for WinForms or WPF?

Comment: It is Windows Form Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WinForms you could use the following to clear all wanted controls.

```
public void ClearTextBoxes(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            if (!(c.Parent is NumericUpDown))
            {
                ((TextBox)c).Clear();
            }
        }
        else if (c is NumericUpDown)
        {
            ((NumericUpDown)c).Value = 0;
        }
        else if (c is ComboBox)
        {
            ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        if (c.HasChildren)
        {
            ClearTextBoxes(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to activate it you simply add a button in the form with the following in the code-behind.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearTextBoxes(this);
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think the condition `HasChildren` is needed.

Comment: It will still work without, but with the `if` statement it will only go through children controls if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works except one thing. The numericupdown are also cleared (empty) instead being set to value 0.

Comment: Setting to -1 should help maintaining the values opposed to clearing

Comment: For -1 it gives exception that value of range

Comment: The problem is that it is based on a `TextBox`.

Comment: ahaa thats why. So there is no why ?

Comment: Now thats really cool. Thanks alot DJ KRAZE, Fuji for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ClearTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        ClearTextBoxes(c);
        if(c is TextBox) c.Text = string.Empty;
        if(c is ComboBox) c.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

or

```
public void ClearTextBoxes(Control ctrl) 
{ 
    if (ctrl != null) 
    { 
        foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls) 
        { 
            if (c is TextBox)
            {   
                ((TextBox)c).Text = string.empty; 
            } 

            if(c is ComboBox)
            {
                ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            ClearTextBoxes(c); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1) This only clears top level textboxes 2) it only clears textboxes

Comment: 1) This *still* only clears textboxes 2) You are now not clearing the top level control.

Comment: this does it recursively I have just tested.. please point out if I am doing something incorrectly .. I am looking at Parent Controls it should still loop thru Child controls with the parent..

Comment: This won't work as you are not casting c. `if (c is TextBox) ((TextBox)c).Clear();`

Comment: you don't have to cast I am testing if it is TextBox then it clears.. and this actually does work Fuji so not sure what you are taling about.. it's always better to Check the type rather before you decide to cast the type

Comment: Maybe you are running a different version, but my `Control` does not know what `SelectedIndex` or `Clear()` is.

Comment: I will post another example based on what you are talking about ..I am very familiar with both ways of doing it.. hold one sec

Comment: `'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Clear' and no extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found`

Comment: Fuji I updated it to show that the second version will work. The version I am using I forgot that I have created an extension method ..my apologies..

Comment: Not a problem sorry about the confusion Fuji

Answer (score -1):

If this is WinForms iterate through all controls and reset them

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if (c is TextBox)
   {
        ((TextBox)c).Text = "";
   }
   else if (c is ComboBox)
   {
        ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex = 0;
   }
   else if (c is NumericUpDown)
   {
        ((NumericUpDown)c).Value= 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: you should probably want to check if the control is of type `ComboBox` rather than casting...